# RuntimeBinderException when accessing ValueTuple item via dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, valuetuple

I am facing a really weird behavior of `ValueTuple<T1,T2>` passed from another assembly, accessed using `dynamic`. This code under specific circumstances throws `RuntimeBinderException` at the last line:

```
TupleTest(out var t);
(dynamic i1, dynamic i2) = t;
dynamic a = i1.Item1;
```

The message is:

```
'System.ValueType' does not contain a definition for 'Item1'
```

`TupleTest` function is defined in another assembly like this:

```
static void TupleTest(out ValueTuple<dynamic, dynamic> result) {
    result = default;

    result.Item1 = (new Priv(), new Priv());
    result.Item2 = (new Priv(), new Priv());
}
```

Where empty `class Priv { }` has no visibility modifiers.

However, if I add `public class Priv`, the issue goes away.

I understand, that binder could have had problems accessing instance members of `Priv`, but in this case I am not getting to that yet! All I am trying to do is to access field `Item1` of `ValueTuple`.

Interestingly, if `Priv` implements some public interface `IFoo`, then replacing `result.Item1 = (new Priv(), new Priv());` with `result.Item1 = ((IFoo)new Priv(), (IFoo)new Priv())` allows `dynamic a = i1.Item1` to succeed.

Does that mean, that I can't use `dynamic` at all to access any public fields, whose value type is private (can only be possible with generics), defined elsewhere?

Comment: Works on my machine. And on [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIBoYQ3cAHwACABgAEwgIwBuALAAoYQCZRi4QGZJUgGyTl2gOyKA3ovEXJW6XuEAWcQFkobIgAoAlOctmFl8QCQACpwDBBBKDBuHHAw4gBuUAjiMB7yfpYBbgAmAJ5EUDRsFOJsUtzieQVFJWzKHuIAvCnpAf5VhcXiUE2lUgB0BKQ0st4WAL6KY9q2DiFhEchRMXEAalC4cOGhjAA8HTUVB8UAfOJIyHip077+/hdXvdlYOPjp0/coV4PDUr1uRAgAHdxAAFBBseKeCqAkHgyGeNIfSwPfA/JgGZoA4FgiFQjwwnHw/FIjITRSTBTqAzE8QmcSUoA=)

Comment: @PauloMorgado `Priv` must be declared in a different assembly to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `Priv` is not accessible to the code trying to access it.

The accessibility of the types in `dynamic` must abide to the compiler rules.

The error message is not very helpful, though.